# Can't detect usb media while booting ubuntu 18.04 in in msi gs65 stealth thin 1060 maxq

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

I'm trying to install ubuntu 18.04 (Preferably dual boot) in msi gs65 8re stealth thin pre-installed with windows 10 but the bootable usb media is not found while booting. It has got 3 usb 3.1 only no 2.0. So, I am guessing my issue might be related to this.

I have Disabled fast boot and secure boot and boot mode to UEFI only.

**Software and Devices I am using to boot and test.**

- RUFUS and ubuntu startup Disk to create bootable ubuntu from iso. In RUFUS I have seleted all option available (MBR and GPT for UEFI and also BIOS).
- I am using two usb drive : 16 GB Kensington Thumb drive and 8Gb usb both were old one so I think its usb 2.0 (Not sure how to check)
- The Laptop I am testing the results were dell inspiron 14 n4110 (Non UEFI) and dell inspiron 11 3000(UEFI).

**Results**
For inspiron 11, I can boot and try ubuntu for both drive for all bootable settings mentioned above. Bit, for inspiron 14, only mbr with bios mode. However, when I try to boot msi gs65, it displays no media found. Both media is detected and can be used for normal operation from windows 10. Only issue is while booting Anyone have come with similar issues?? I have been stuck with this for 3 days now. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have just received my GS65 Stealth Thin and the first thing I did was install Ubuntu 18.04 too. :)  Aside from switching the order of the boot devices, the only other setting I had to change in the BIOS was to disable *Secure Boot*.  To enter the BIOS you should press the `DELETE` key repeatedly before the OS boots straight after power-on.

Here's a screenshot of the setting:

[image: Disable Secure Boot]

Make sure you *Save and Exit* so the changes take effect.

If you chose not to set USB drives as the first priority in the boot order, instead you can also hit `F11` during boot to select a boot device for a one-off boot.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: My GS65 is on pre-order, when I finally receive it I'll be heading down the same route and then maybe I can verify if those settings are actually in the BIOS.